# Scope of SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like to know the scope of

> SharedPreferences

. I want to set some variables which can be used in  entire application all the time untill unless  the application uninstalled by the user. Can I use SharedPreferences to save the value?? I know that I can use database, But I want to know the scope of SharedPreferences, so that I can use SharedPreferences properly. Somebody please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows
>   you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data
>   types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data:
>   booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. ***This data will persist
>   across user sessions (even if your application is killed).***

You can use `SharedPreferences`. If you curious about the life of `SharedPreferences` then its clear that it will be available for entire life of your application. But keep in mind that All application storage looses data when user clears the application data, so that time `SharedPreferences` will also loose the value.

Instead of using db, you can use `SharedPreferences`.

Ref : [data-storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Honestly speaking I am not very sure about that but that could be the  sessions until user clears the application data. When I will have more details I will update you, sure.

Comment: Can't catch your last statement... `Instead, you can use SharedPreferences`. Did you mean another thing?

Comment: @XtremeBiker That was for DB. I said you can use `SharedPreferences` instead of db.

Answer (score 2):

you can use SharedPreferences to save variables within your application.
**As a example you can use SharedPreferences in a game to save the score/points.**
In this case if you are dealing with less number of variables i think the best way is
SharedPreferences.
Hope my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically use small amount of data in key value pair form. And it will store all premitive type data with key value pair. 
it is basically use to save password. session key, authuntication key etc.

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` are stored in an .xml file, placed in your app's private data area.

The file's path is something like:
`/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/PREFS_NAME.xml`

and will be deleted only when the user uninstalls your app or clears the app data through Settings > Apps.

> Can I use SharedPreferences to save the value?

Yes, you can use `SharedPreferences` to save any primitive value and retrieve it later on using the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel to SharedPreferences there's a persistance data which is not shared in the whole application but in an single Activity: [Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). This is usefull to store values like filters parameters or temporary configurations.
Example from doc:

```
// SharedPreferences
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```